# Within and between group factor in linear mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

Could I please get some advice on coding a linear mixed model for looking at between and within group effect.
I have 2 Timepoints (Baseline and 12 weeks Post intervention) and 2 groups (Ex1 and Ex2).

```r
Outcome variable ~ Group*Timepoint + (1|ID)
```

I know this will answer the first and second points but I want to run one model so I can answer all three

1. I want to see if there is an interaction between timepoint and group. (i.e after the intervention did the outcome variable improve more in Ex2 than Ex1).
2. I want to see if regardless of group did my outcome variable change after 12 weeks
3. And finally (this is part I am struggling with), *within* each group did my outcome variable change from Baseline to 12 weeks post?

```r
Outcome variable ~ Group*Timepoint + (1+Timepoint|Group)
```

OR

```r
Outcome variable ~ Group*Timepoint + (1+Timepoint|Group/ID)
```

Comment: In your 3rd point, when you say "within each group", do you mean within each `Group` , or with each `ID` ? From the wording of point 3 it seems you mean within each `Group` but the title of the question says it's within "subject" - that is, within `ID`. Please clarify.

Comment: My apologies, I mean within group. I will edit the title to say 'group'

Comment: OK but the first paragraph says "between and within subject effect". So is it between/within subject AND group ?

Comment: @RobertLong Apologies again, first time posting a question, I am not interested in the within/between subjects only with the within/between group effect.I have also edited the question